# How to extract hours and minutes from a series of strings in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, string

I have been stuck on this seemingly simple problem for hours. I would like to convert the following strings to minutes. (Or hours and minutes if I could).

```
foo['stringtime'] = pd.Series(['1 hour and 59 minutes','2 hours', np.nan, '38 minutes', '4 hours and 31 minutes'])

#What I've tried:
foo['stringtime'] = foo['stringtime'].str.replace(r'hours?','').str.replace(' minutes','').str.split(' and ')
```

However this would create a situation where `'2 hours'` and `'38 minutes'` become `['2']` and `['38']`

```
#What I would like to happen:
foo.head()
output:
119
120
NaN (or 0)
38
271
```

Is there any beautiful elegant pythonic way to do this?

Comment: are there only hours and minutes for the whole data or it's just an example?

Comment: It's a complete dataset and this is a column. This is just an example.

Comment: I understand that, I was asking whether something like "1 day and 22 hours and 19 minutes" can happen, or is it constrained to hours and minutes only

Comment: No it is about video length. There are no days of video included :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Using Regex.

**Ex:**

```
import re

def p_time(val):
    try:
        t = 0
        h = re.search(r"(\d+) hour(s)?", val)
        if h:
            t += int(h.group(1)) * 60
        m = re.search(r"(\d+) minute(s)?", val)
        if m:
            t += int(m.group(1))
        return t
    except:
        pass
    return 0

s = pd.Series(['1 hour and 59 minutes','2 hours', np.nan, '38 minutes', '4 hours and 31 minute'])
print(s.apply(p_time).astype(int))
```

**Output:**

```
0    119
1    120
2      0
3     38
4    271
dtype: int32
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! However I still do not udnerstand the difference between the  first parentheses, capture group, and the second with the optional s. shouldn't that just be normal s?

Comment: That is just to catch both case `minutes` & `minute`

Answer (score 1):

Another way might be just to use `numexpr` to evaluate a numerical equation:

```py
import numexpr

foo = pd.Series(['1 hour and 59 minutes','2 hours', np.nan, '38 minutes', '4 hours and 31 minutes'])

(foo.str.replace(r' hours?','*60').str.replace(' minutes','').str.replace(' and ', '+')
    .fillna('0').apply(numexpr.evaluate))
```

**Output:**

```
0    119
1    120
2      0
3     38
4    271
```